# Have the Colonial Marines met the Aliens before?

Tags: alien-franchise

In the movie [Aliens (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/), the following exchange occurs as the marines are on route to the stricken colony:

> Hudson: Is this gonna be a standup fight, sir, or another bughunt?
>
> Gorman: All we know is that there's still no contact with the colony, and that a xenomorph may be involved.
>
> Frost: Excuse me sir, a-a what?
>
> Gorman: A xenomorph.
>
> Hicks: It's a bughunt.

I know that *xenomorph* is the name given to the Alien species in the franchise, which would mean that at the very least Gorman knows about them. Yet as the subsequent events show, the marines have no idea what they are in for, and are taken by complete surprise.

So what are the xenomorphs Gorman is talking about? And what "bugs" are they talking about hunting?

Comment: We really need a better "name" for the "Alien" species in the Alien franchise; maybe this will come with a sequel to Prometheus?

Comment: @PaulGregoire (many years later) unfortunately, nothing good ever came from Prometheus or its sequel :P Let's pretend they never existed!

Comment: @AndresF. agreed, sequel could have been so much more :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, or they'd have taken  off and nuked the whole site from orbit as soon as it became clear what they were dealing with...

Gorman uses 'xenomorph' because it means he can show off the fact that he knows long words in Greek, it's another instance of him believing that his Staff College education puts him above the grunts despite his lack of field experience.

As to the wider point, the whole conversation *implies* that there are other alien species that the Marines have come across (and also the mention of 'Arcturian poon-tang' whilst the Marines are eating breakfast) *and* that said species are at least hostile to humans if not actively belligerent. The Marines clearly place anything non-human (or *humanoid*, I suppose I have to exclude the likes of Bishop here) under the category of 'bugs' - the Bug Stomper artwork on the side of the dropship cockpit reinforces this.

The out-of-print RPG detailed other alien species that humans had come across, as I recall they were largely benign but there was at least one other species that caused problems for humans, I suspect this was an attempt to a) make the game not totally about Aliens, and b) give some substance to the referenced conversation.

Comment: Greek, actually.

Comment: Just looked up the etymology of xenomorph. Apparently it means "alien life form". That silly Gorman!

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I'd always assumed it was Latin, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 11):

They had met other aliens and it was not a big deal, note detreich and Hudson saying something like:

"apparently she saw an alien once"
"well whoopy *cough* do"

So meeting aliens was nothing new.

However watch as they first struggle to locate the aliens as they are unprepared for creatures that do not show up in infrared, they also are confused by the alien nest. They are unsure what the walls are made of

"it must be some sort of secreted resin"
"yeah, but secreted from what?"

They are also shown to be far too relaxed (sleeping in the drop ship, messing around and joking) than they would be if they were aware of this type of enemy. They are like a reflection of the American army in the first year of Vietnam where they are complacent and think their technology will win out

Burke "they are packing state of the art firepower . There is nothing they cannot handle"

They drastically underestimate their enemy despite Ripley's warnings.

If they knew this type of enemy was potentially waiting they would have been far more cautious.

Comment: I think the Weyland-Yutani corporation, or at least Burke, are aware of the Aliens (with capital "A"), but the Marines certainly aren't. They just have fought different aliens before, and probably think Ripley means those. See [PhilPursglove's reply](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18206/770).

Comment: I thought that they were only aware of it from Ripley, hence they sent Newt's family out to see if the ship was there.  When they lost contact they correctly guessed that Ripley was telling the truth.  

Although I am not sure if it mentions Burke had approval from the company for what he was doing?  When he was talking to Ripley it sounded like he had been trying to keep the entire thing quiet, he had not even told the colonists what they were walking into.

Comment: I think so too: whether with WY's approval or not, Burke was being sly. I don't think he ever disclosed the truth to anyone, Marines _or_ Ripley. Also, keep in mind the theatrical cut doesn't show the colonist scenes ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, that is true

Comment: I'm not sure about WY knowing the critters from before _Aliens_, but they probably are aware something happened to the Nostromo, in Ripley's first mission. And given the behavior of Ash in that movie, they might even know the Aliens from before that!

Comment: But if that were the case why would they have put the colony there and never investigated?  From the enquiry it seemed like they had no information about the Nostromo and found Ripley's story highly doubtful.  They even stated that she claimed to had found something never recorded once in over 300 surveyed worlds.  Your point about Ash though, is very interesting.  The people who put him on board must have had an idea that something good was on that planet - although this might have been covered up I guess

Comment: If you look at the entire cannon including AVP/Predator, WY are well aware of the "Alien" species and its probably the primary reason that the Nostromo is sent to LV-426 in 2122.

Comment: I suspect that was decided after the originals were made. See my above questions on wy's statements and actions in aliens. Although it does leave questions about who sent the nostromo there in alien. Was it clarified that the company was the same?

Comment: @Mondain I'm not sure AVP is canon at all :) Yes, I know about the movies (yuck!) and the crossover comics, but let me put it this way: do Ridley Scott and James Cameron consider them to be in the same universe?

Answer (score 1):

"Bug hunt" is probably an homage to starship troopers, the Book mind you.  It was published in 1959 and referred to the aliens that humanity was at war with, as Bugs.  My guess is that James Cameron or someone wanted to homage the book being the similarity to the stories.