In Aliens: Did the company marines know what the Xenomorphs were? Also, what races were they aware of?
The marine commander about 25 minutes in referred to 'Xenomorphs.' That initially made me wonder whether they were aware, but in-universe that term is a vague catch-all. It still makes me wonder: did they know?
Furthermore, one of the marines says "Arcturian poontang." So they're aware of some alien races. What races were they aware of? And does that include the Yautja?

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! You have two interesting questions here, please could you [edit] your post to focus on a single, answerable question. Of course  you may ask the second one separately (include a link to this one if it helps with context).

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/have-the-colonial-marines-met-the-aliens-before addresses the first point.

https://www.reddit.com/r/LV426/comments/18hrlu4/in_aliens_how_do_the_marines_not_actually_know/ has some other details from the extended universe.

Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40549/in-the-alien-universe-were-other-extra-terrestrials-encountered-before-the-alie
