# Why the need for a Science Officer on a cargo vessel?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Just been watching the excellent *Alien* movie and wondered: why would the Nostromo, an innocuous civilian cargo vessel, have a "science officer" on board?

If you need a Science Officer, how about a doctor?  A dentist? A surgeon in case one of the crew's appendix bursts?

If not, why not?

Comment: Since finding new alien lifeforms is apparently not uncommon in this universe (see for example https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46806/why-did-the-crew-of-nostromo-not-seem-too-surprised-by-new-alien-life ), then it makes quite a lot of sense to have a science officer on board.

Comment: Was "Science Officer" a full-time job?  Was the officer mainly concerned with keeping the refinery runnning?

Comment: I mean as a science officer, I assume Ash has a working knowledge of all sciences, including medicine. He provided excellent care to Kane, aside from the minor parasitic infection he unluckily failed to spot.

Comment: Was a science officer concerned with ranging, telemetry and communication? With the propulsion of a ginormous—by the 20th century standards of when the film was made—spaceship? With tests and reasoning about the chemical composition of stuff—atmospheres, dust, organics—the ship may encounter?

Comment: As for the lack of a doctor, some of the ships in the franchise feature a fully automated medical bay, no doctor required.  I'm thinking of the one from *Prometheus*, which being a prequel implies that the technology existed in the time of the first movie as well.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - The ship has an autodoc, which seems capable of diagnosing and treating most ailments.

Comment: Never mind about the Science Officer, why didn't they have an HR Officer?

Answer (score 25):

Based on Ash's actions in the early part of the film we can ascertain that the Science Officer is responsible for a range of sciencey things, notably **the safety and wellbeing of their very large and expensive refinery** as well as **orbital mechanics for the Nostromo**.

> The tug and refinery rotated, performing a massive pirouette in the vastness of space. Light appeared at the stern of the tug as her secondary engines fired briefly.
> 'Equatorial orbit nailed,' declared Ash. Below them, the miniature world rotated unconcernedly.
> 'Give me an EG pressure reading.'
> Ash examined gauges, spoke without turning to face Dallas. 'Three point four five en slash em squared. . . About five psia, sir.'
> 'Shout if it changes.'
> 'You worried about redundancy management disabling CMGS control when we're busy elsewhere?'
> 'Yeah.'
> 'CMG control is inhibited via DAS/DCS. We'll augment with TACS and monitor through ATMDG land computer interface. Feel better now?'
> 'A lot.'
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: Official Novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_(novel))</sup></sub>

His console contains **information about the ship's atmosphere, ensuring that it remains breathable and uncontaminated.**

> Ash studied his own console. Along with the others, it was
> independently powered in the event of a massive energy failure such as
> they were presently experiencing. 'Air in all compartments shows no
> sign of contamination from outside atmosphere. I think we're still
> tight, sir.'

He also supports Captain Dallas in **deciphering the distress signal.**

> 'The emergency lies elsewhere - specifically, in the unlisted system
> we've recently entered. We should be closing on the particular planet
> concerned right now.' He glanced at Ash, who rewarded him with a
> confirming nod. 'We've picked up a transmission from another source.
> It's garbled and apparently took Mother some time to puzzle out, but
> it's definitely a distress signal.'

He also **acts as the ship's primary medic** after an injury occurs, although he goes to pains to indicate that he's not a doctor.

> 'Long-term prognosis?'
> The science officer looked hesitant. 'I'm not a medical officer. The Nostromo isn't big enough to rate one.'
> 'Or important enough. I know that. But you're the closest thing we've got.

Comment: That doesn't look right. 3.45 N/m² is 0.0005 psia, not 5.

Comment: So in short, because it sounds cooler than "safety officer"

Comment: @ChrisH The US Navy (when I was serving in it) had independent duty corpsmen on destroyers and frigates.  Those ships were not big enough to rate a doctor (like a carrier or an amphibious ship) but the IDC was qualified to deal with a certain level of trauma, disease, and injury.